# Angular object turns into array after including the foreign keys

Tags: .net, angular

Currently im trying to include my foreign keys to get easier data access to my user data. The problem is after im including my foreign key model in my backend, im getting back an array like you will see on my screenshots. Including the foreign key in my backend looks like:

Backend without inlcuding my foreign key:

```html
// GET: api/Personens/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Personen>> GetPersonen(Guid id)
        {
            var personen = await _context.Personens.FindAsync(id);

            if (personen == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return personen;
        }
```

```html
 // GET: api/Personens/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Personen>>> GetPersonen(Guid id)
        {
            var personen = await _context.Personens.FindAsync(id);

            return await _context.Personens.Where(p => p.PersonId == id).Include(p => p.Unternehmensbereich).ToListAsync();
        }
```

This works fine, but the array is currently my problem.
Before im including it, a simple

```html
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      const id = params['id'];
      this.pService
        .getUser(id)
        .subscribe(data => { this.person = data;  console.log(this.person); })
        })
```

was possible. After including it i have no chance to reach the data, because the backend turns it into an array and i get a undefined value back.

Before my including it looks like that in my console:
https://ibb.co/RHFHp2L

After:
https://ibb.co/bHtgZLB

I know that it transforms into an array like that because of the .ToListAsync in my backend, but i dont know how to handle it.

Comment: Not sure why you're calling ToList() in the first place. Something along the lines of `return await _context.Personens.Include(p => p.Unternehmensbereich).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.PersonId == id);` should do the trick. Note that I'm not in front of my computer, so this is from the top of my head.

Comment: Suureee wow. Im such an idiot.  I copy and pasted it because i handled some other models and forgot that firstordefault in this case would be possible.. ty!